# regex to check for a valid regex pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to write a validation class in php and have hit a snag. I am using the following code to check a value against a defined regex pattern but when I try to run the script I receive an error message saying:

"Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Empty regular expression in C:\wamp\www\valid\Class.Validate.php on line 109"

Can anyone spot my mistake ?

```
   public function is_regex($var, $expression, $msg)
   {
      if (trim($var) <> "") {
          $Valid = (bool)preg_match($expression, $var);
          if ($Valid == false) {
              return $msg;
          }
      }     
   }
```

and I am using this to call the function

```
array('Type'=>'Regex','Var'=>$_POST['test'], 'Expression'=>'[A-Za-z]{1,20}$','Msg'=>'Expression does not match')
```

Comment: hm... you send this array as a 1st argument?

Comment: The problem lies in the `is_regex` invocation code that you have *not* shown here. (Also I'd avoid mixed-case array keys. That's not very webapp.)

Comment: What's line 109 of `C:\wamp\www\valid\Class.Validate.php`? Where is the connection between the function and the array you are "using ... to call the function"?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you need to enclose regexp into enclosure characters, for example |
so your checking array will be like

```
array('Type'=>'Regex','Var'=>$_POST['test'], 'Expression'=>'|[A-Za-z]{1,20}$|','Msg'=>'Expression does not match')
```

You can also define character in function, but in this case if you'll have this character in regexp, you'll need to escape it

Comment: Tried the example you provided and no go. I don't think the problem lies in how I am calling the function, but rather the function itself is not formatted properly, but after trying many varitions of single and double quotes for the variables I have come up with nothing that works.